# Json Data not loading in Fragment?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

**Hi Dear Developers,
I hope all of you doing great I am developing Android News app where I have used bottom navigation drawer combination with fragments. When I click each items json not displaying I have used Retrofit for network call.**

below MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends BottomBarHolderActivity implements AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, BBCFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, CNNFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, CBCNewsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        // private ApiService apiService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

        NavigationPage page1 = new NavigationPage("AllJazeera", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.alljazeera), AllJazeeraFragment.newInstance());
        NavigationPage page2 = new NavigationPage("Support", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bbc_icon), CNNFragment.newInstance());
        NavigationPage page3 = new NavigationPage("Billing", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cnn_icon), AllJazeeraFragment.newInstance());
        NavigationPage page4 = new NavigationPage("Profile", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cbc_icon), CBCNewsFragment.newInstance());

        List<NavigationPage> navigationPages = new ArrayList<>();
        navigationPages.add(page1);
        navigationPages.add(page2);
        navigationPages.add(page3);
        navigationPages.add(page4);

        super.setupBottomBarHolderActivity(navigationPages);
    }


    public void onClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

*below my AllJazeeraFragment class*
where I have implemented network call using retrofit

```
public class AllJazeeraFragment extends Fragment {


    public NewsAdapter adapter;
    public Article articleList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;

    public static AllJazeeraFragment newInstance() {
        return new AllJazeeraFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alljazeera_fragment, container, false);

        NewsInterface apiService = NewsClient.getApiService();
        Call <Article> call = apiService.getAllJazeera();

        call.enqueue(new Callback <Article>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Article> call, Response <Article> response) {

                articleList = response.body();
                recyclerView =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                adapter = new NewsAdapter((List<Article>) articleList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <Article> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = (AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    }


}
```

below my alljazeera_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**below my BBCFragment.java file**

```
public class BBCFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;
    Article articleList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    NewsAdapter adapter;
    public static BBCFragment newInstance() {
        return new BBCFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bbc_fragment, container, false);

        NewsInterface apiService = NewsClient.getApiService();
        Call <Article> call = apiService.getBBC();

        call.enqueue(new Callback <Article>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Article> call, Response <Article> response) {

                articleList = response.body();
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                adapter = new NewsAdapter((List<Article>) articleList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Article> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    }


}
```

*below bbc_fragment.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*below my interface where I am calling ending points*
    public interface NewsInterface {

```
    @GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=al-jazeera-english&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
    Call <Article> getAllJazeera();

    @GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=cbc-news&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
    Call <Article> getCbC();

    @GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
    Call <Article> getBBC();

    @GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
    Call <Article> getCNN();

}
```

below news client class

```
 public class NewsClient  {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/";

    /**
     * Get Retrofit Instance
     */
    private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get API Service
     *
     * @return API Service
     */
    public static NewsInterface getApiService() {
        return getRetrofitInstance().create(NewsInterface.class);
    }
    }
```

*below json response from api*

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 9,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Al Jazeera",
            "title": "Former Maldives leader Gayoom freed on bail a week after election",
            "description": "Former president's release came a week after half-brother Abdulla Yameen lost the presidential election.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/09/maldives-leader-gayoom-freed-bail-week-election-180930150231895.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/30/367ab1ceb832482b9db0c4b22cadf2f5_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T16:48:00Z",
            "content": "Former Maldives president Maumoon Abdul Gayoom has been released on bail a week after his estranged half-brother Abdulla Yameen was defeated in a presidential election. Gayoom, the Indian Ocean island nation's longest-serving leader, and his legislator son Fa… [+2862 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Faras Ghani",
            "title": "Why are humans killing 100 million sharks every year?",
            "description": "Increasing consumption of shark fin soup and illegal fishing may lead to extinction of certain species, experts warn.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/09/humans-killing-100-million-sharks-year-180923150037790.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/23/1ebd7c07e6dc49b095a58fe7c849a872_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T14:02:00Z",
            "content": "Humans kill an estimated 100 million sharks annually and experts have warned that certain species face extinction if the trend continues. Consumption of shark fin soup, primarily in China and Vietnam, is the biggest reason behind the massive figure, contribut… [+6786 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Al Jazeera",
            "title": "Real Madrid football club honours Palestine activist Ahed Tamimi",
            "description": "Palestinian activist, who spent eight months in Israeli prison, is welcomed at Bernabeu stadium by the football club.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/09/real-madrid-football-club-honours-palestine-activist-ahed-tamimi-180930100616622.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/30/fa170d306f5d41a5bafbef373f20da1b_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T12:09:00Z",
            "content": "Palestinian activist Ahed Tamimi, whose arrest last year drew international condemnation, has been honoured by Spanish football club Real Madrid after she was released from Israeli prison. The 17-year-old was arrested in December 2017 after a video of her sla… [+2066 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Sheetal Dhir",
            "title": "It's time to speak about the economic cost of sexual assault",
            "description": "The Kavanaugh scandal is an opportunity to finally talk about the economic toll sexual assault takes on our society.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/opinion/time-speak-economic-cost-sexual-assault-180930071453246.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/30/1cf27079db8745d0b2995f820445b739_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T11:45:00Z",
            "content": "I recently did a straw poll of the women in my life and realised that I know more survivors of sexual assault than I do mothers. The national statistics are staggering - according to the National Sexual Violence Resource Center, \"one in three women in the US … [+9518 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Anumeha Yadav",
            "title": "In Jharkhand, a tribal assertion met with fierce police crackdown",
            "description": "Authorities say they are legally acquiring land to be used for 'development' projects, but villagers tell another story.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/jharkhand-tribal-assertion-met-fierce-police-crackdown-180929223820429.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/28/619b6054917b46e3ac4f6813f60fe3cd_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T07:41:00Z",
            "content": "Jharkhand, India: It was dusk in Uduburu, the time that farmers usually return home after working in the paddy fields, but the hamlet in the eastern Indian state of Jharkhand was deserted. The village square was empty and the mud huts were locked. After darkn… [+13300 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Shereena Qazi",
            "title": "How Afghanistan fell in love with cricket",
            "description": "Cricket was imported by Afghan refugees from Pakistan, banned by the Taliban and finally embraced by government.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/09/afghanistan-fell-love-cricket-180928141048315.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/28/f7c2ddb6514642a7bb60e29ea3b6a37c_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T06:47:00Z",
            "content": "Afghanistan recently ended its 2018 Asia Cup journey in Dubai with a series of impressive performances, filling Afghans at home with joy. With victories against Sri Lanka and Bangladesh, a tie against India and a competitive effort against Pakistan, the team … [+5118 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Al Jazeera",
            "title": "Indonesia: Rescuers search for survivors after quake, tsunami",
            "description": "Rescuers rushing to reach people trapped by the quake and tsunami that has killed over 400 people in Palu city alone.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/09/indonesia-rescuers-search-survivors-quake-tsunami-180930052755793.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/30/59c2bcfc48a046f78ae30a9548511fcc_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T06:44:00Z",
            "content": "Rescue teams in Indonesia have struggled to reach communities devastated by a major earthquake and tsunami on Sulawesi island, with a toll of more than 400 killed expected to rise sharply as contact is restored with remote areas. Amid the levelled trees, over… [+3207 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "Charlotte Mitchell",
            "title": "Six months to go until Brexit: All you need to know",
            "description": "Will Brexit definitely happen? Is a trade deal expected? What will happen to migrants? How will the economy be affected?",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/09/months-brexit-180923173227311.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/28/e45c2ba07b944276b369e3fe291bf21b_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-29T08:17:00Z",
            "content": "Britain is due to leave the EU in six months' time, at 23:00 GMT on March 29, 2019. Here are five things to know: 1. Will Brexit definitely happen? The UK government remains committed to reaching an agreement with the EU before negotiations end in March, howe… [+9323 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "al-jazeera-english",
                "name": "Al Jazeera English"
            },
            "author": "James Rippingale",
            "title": "The toll of burying Grenfell's dead",
            "description": "For those who cared for the living and the dead after the Grenfell Tower fire, the struggle for justice continues.",
            "url": "http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/toll-burying-grenfell-dead-180926072155075.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2018/9/28/faafdfc4216b47bbb86282cf33fca7df_18.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-29T06:40:00Z",
            "content": "\"I'd never heard of Grenfell before. I didn't think there were that many Muslims in Chelsea,\" exclaims Abu Mumin, 48, of Eden Care, a Muslim end-of-life support charity run from a compact, green and white-walled Whitechapel office. It's a frantic Monday and t… [+9655 chars]"
        }
    ]
}
```

*below my NewsAdapter class*

```
  public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {


        private List<Article> articleList;

        public NewsAdapter(List<Article> articleList) {
            this.articleList = articleList;
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.news_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new NewsViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder, int i) {
            Article article = articleList.get(i);
            newsViewHolder.articleAuthor.setText(article.getAuthor());
            newsViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(article.getTitle());
            newsViewHolder.articleDescription.setText(article.getDescription());
            Picasso.get().load(article.getUrlToImage()).into(newsViewHolder.articleImage);


        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return articleList.size();
        }

        public final static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // TextView articleAuthor, articleTitle, articleDescription, articleUrl;
            //  ImageView articleImage;
            @BindView(R.id.article_Image)
            ImageView articleImage;
            @BindView(R.id.article_Author)
            TextView articleAuthor;
            @BindView(R.id.article_Title)
            TextView articleTitle;

            @BindView(R.id.article_Description)
            TextView articleDescription;

            @BindView(R.id.article_Url)
            TextView articleUrl;


            public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            }
        }
    }
```

below my Article model class
public class Article {

```
@SerializedName("source")
@Expose
private Source source;
@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
private String author;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
@Expose
private String urlToImage;
@SerializedName("publishedAt")
@Expose
private String publishedAt;
@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
private String content;

public Source getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(Source source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrlToImage() {
    return urlToImage;
}

public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
    this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
}

public String getPublishedAt() {
    return publishedAt;
}

public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
    this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

}

Comment: have you set the internet permission in manifest?

Comment: @Yes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: @NileshPanchal I set internet permission already

Comment: check if your call go inside onFailure or onResponse, and post your newsAdapter class plz

Comment: @Vodet, I have added newsadapter class please check my code thanks

Comment: @Vodet I have called data is comming but failing in recyclerview I did not understand where I am make mistake

Comment: Ok I got it, post your Article model plz

Comment: @Vodet please check the code

Comment: @Vodet I have posted model class

Comment: @Vodet did you check it thanks

Comment: Navneet is faster than me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created your model class incorrectly, first of all you will need one more model class like this

**ArticleResponse.java**

```
    public class ArticleResponse {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("totalResults")
@Expose
private Integer totalResults;
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
private List<Article> articles = null;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Integer getTotalResults() {
return totalResults;
}

public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
this.totalResults = totalResults;
}

public List<Article> getArticles() {
return articles;
}

public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
this.articles = articles;
}

}
```

> Now change this `public Article articleList;` to this `public
>   ArrayList<Article> articleList=new ArrayList();`

Now change your network call like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alljazeera_fragment, container, false);

    NewsInterface apiService = NewsClient.getApiService();
    Call <ArticleResponse> call = apiService.getAllJazeera();

    call.enqueue(new Callback <ArticleResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call <ArticleResponse> call, Response <ArticleResponse> response) {

            articleList = new ArrayList<>(response.body().getArticles());
            recyclerView =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            adapter = new NewsAdapter(articleList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call <ArticleResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Now change interface also like this

```
 @GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=al-jazeera-english&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
Call <ArticleResponse> getAllJazeera();

@GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=cbc-news&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
Call <ArticleResponse> getCbC();

@GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
Call <ArticleResponse> getBBC();

@GET("v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=a5cc70bd52c9436785557878f4aa49e1")
Call <ArticleResponse> getCNN();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many issues with your code.

Your json has a list of articles. But your `Call <Article> getAllJazeera()` api returns a `<Article>` instead of `<List<Article>>`. In fact you should have a `ArticleListResponse` sort of model that contains a list of articles and other fields in your json such as

```
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 9,
```

Another issue I see is that your retrofit success callback you are doing

```
            adapter = new NewsAdapter((List<Article>) articleList);
```

even though articleList is not even `List<Article>`. You create an `Article` variable and try to cast it to a list.

You need to make all these changes and then your code might work.